# Polymer > show a 404 for a non existent Neon-Animated-Pages

Tags: javascript, polymer, listener, polymer-1.0

I can't get neon-animated-pages to fire 'iron-select' if you select an index that does not exist.

Actually I can do it if I don't scope the listener to the element.  For example, this catches the event:

```
listeners: {
    'iron-select':'_listIronSelect'
}
```

but this doesn't

```
listeners: {
    'pages.iron-select':'_lisIronSelect'
}
```

Let me be clear that the scoped listener works as long as you select a neon-animated-pages child that exists.  And of course I have to scope that listener because my code has other iron-select being fired off.

If you are wondering why I need this, it is because I select the neon-animated-pages based on the url.  That is how I do routing so I need this so I can show a 404 if needed.

EDIT ******

Here is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3kzssc85/

Comment: Have you tried setting an observer to the property that's bound to your `neon-animated-pages` `selected` property? I think that might work better for you than the actual `iron-select` event

Comment: Just tried it, not luck.  Doesn't change if you select a child that doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you using for your routing? page.js?

Comment: No, I wrote a custom router element.  Grabs the url and selects a neon-animated-page that matches the path attribute in my route.  But I have tried this without routing and it still doesn't work.  Try feeding a non-existent selector to neon-animated pages.  It won't send an iron-select event, but it will change to a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`<neon-animated-pages>.fallbackSelection`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animated-pages#property-fallbackSelection) to fallback to a 404 page when the `selected` page is not found:

```
<neon-animated-pages selected="[[page]]"
                     fallback-selection="404"
                     attr-for-selected="data-name">
  <neon-animatable data-name="one">apple</neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable data-name="404">Page not found...</neon-animatable>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animated-pages/neon-animated-pages.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animated-pages/neon-animatable.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animated-pages/neon-animations.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-input label="Enter 'one', 'two', or 'three'" value="{{page}}"></paper-input>
      <neon-animated-pages selected="[[page]]"
                           fallback-selection="404"
                           entry-animation="fade-in-animation"
                           exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
                           attr-for-selected="data-name">
        <neon-animatable data-name="one">apple</neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable data-name="two">orange</neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable data-name="three">banana</neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable data-name="404">Page not found...</neon-animatable>
      </neon-animated-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties : {
            page: {
              type: String,
              value: 'one'
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zKaOKX?editors=1000)</sup>